# API call for release

Tags: postman, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

API request for releases in Azure DevOps using Postman gives how many release cases at a time? I am getting only 50. Is there any way to increase this number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API. You can specify the parameter `$top`to define the number of releases to get. Default is 50.